# How to parallelize 2 loops in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to make each iteration in different thread (for each of these 2 loops).

```
var = 5
a = -7
b = 7
for i in range(var):
    for j in range(a, b):
        print(i, "   ", j)
```

How can I make it?

UPD:

```
var = 5
a = -7
b = 7
max = 0
for i in range(var):
    for j in range(a, b):
        print(i, "   ", j)
        if i+j>max:
            max=i+j
print(max)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run these two loops in different threads because the second loop have dependency to the data which is produced in first loop.

One way is to run each iteration of first loop in a different thread like this:

```
from threading import Thread
var = 5
a = -7
b = 7

def inner_loop(i):
    for j in range(a, b):
        print(i, "   ", j)

for i in range(var):
    Thread(target=inner_loop, args=[i]).start()
```

Another way is producer consumer pattern. First loop generate `i` value and add it to a queue and second loop read values from queue and generate `j` and print `i` and `j` like this:

```
from threading import Thread

var = 5
a = -7
b = 7

queue = []
finished = False

def inner_loop():
    while not finished or len(queue) > 0:
        if len(queue) == 0:
            continue
        i = queue.pop()
        for j in range(a, b):
            print(i, "   ", j)

def first_loop():
    for i in range(var):
        queue.append(i)
    finished = True

Thread(target=inner_loop).start()
Thread(target=first_loop).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want true multi-threading (which the 'threading' library doesn't do!) use the 'multiprocessing' library. The [introduction section in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction) has a good example.

Comment: The `multiprocessing` library is not thread based; it's not multi-threading, and there are significant differences (no implicitly shared state for one). `threading` is multithreaded, it's just GIL limited, which means you only gain true parallelism when doing blocking work or using third party extension packages (e.g. `numpy`) that release the GIL during intensive CPU work.